# Extracting from a list with different sized elements R

Tags: r, list, subset, stringr

I am currently working with a list of items that has various values returned from str_locate_all(). It returns a list that looks like this

```
library(stringr)
location <- str_locate_all(pattern = matched_query, query_string)
location

[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1  3

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]     2  4
[2,]    11  13
[3,]   221 223

[[3]]
     start end
[1,]    12  14
[2,]   222 224

[[4]]
     start end
[1,]    20  22
```

I would like to subset the list to get and seperate all values under "start" and "end". 
`c(1,2,11,221,12,222,20)`
`c(3,4,13,223,14,224,22)`

When I unlist them, the groups with multiple matches do not retain a "start" "stop" "start" "stop" pattern - they have a "start" "start" "stop" "stop" pattern.

So far I have tried:

```
 sapply(location,'[[',1)
1   2   12   20
```

```
lapply(query_wordsize_location,'[[',1)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
[1] 20
```

```
location[[1]][,1]

start 
    1 

location[[1:4]][,1]
Error in location[[1:4]] : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

I could get it to work with a loop, but I am trying to avoid this since there it is a fairly large-sized list.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, location)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `do.call` in this scenario.

```
location <- list(matrix(1:6, ncol = 2), matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), 
                 matrix(1:2, ncol = 2), matrix(1:6, ncol = 2))
location
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6
#
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
#  
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
#
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6

do.call(rbind, location)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6
# [4,]    1    3
# [5,]    2    4
# [6,]    1    2
# [7,]    1    4
# [8,]    2    5
# [9,]    3    6
```